# mysql jdbc apply exceeding username max length (16 char)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a system that mostly written in java. This system has a simple MySQL user permission administrator. But now we getting started to work with more users and the length for the username is now over 16 chars. I modified all username length property in all mysql system tables. In Webmin and PhPMyAdmin modifying the password and table <=> user relations works correctly. But in this java program all operation witch associated with long usernames will be stopped with throwned SQLException with message: String ' ...long username...' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16).

So looks like the problem is in jdbc. How can i force to apply long usernames in SQL operations?
(com.mysql.jdbc (5.1.24))

Query String:

```
st.execute("CREATE USER '"+user+"'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nothing';");
st.execute("SET PASSWORD FOR '"+user+"'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('"+passwd+"');");
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: String '...long username...' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.ja$
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2758)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
```

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace. Also, when you talk about username you mean the database username or your particular username from a `USER` table (or similar)?

Comment: I mean at username is: all "User" field in all tables in mysql database, but this query String with valid user data works.
(if i execute in phpMyAdmin, or in webmin or in mysql command on linux)

Comment: You should rather think about your naming conventions - even large companys with > 10k users come along with userids of 8 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution:
Use

```
"INSERT mysql.user (Host,user,Password) VALUES 'localhost','"+user+"',PASSWORD('"+passwd+"');");
```

instread of

```
SET PASSWORD FOR '"+user+"'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('"+passwd+"');
```

The MySQL will not know, that you modify the password or create user, just run the statement.

Comment: The table definition for mysql.user has user as type char(16), and mysql will truncate any user names longer than 16 characters.  If you have strict sql mode on, you'll get an error.  If you don't the server will quietly truncate the user field with a warning.

Comment: Yes first you need to grown the length of the fields, execute this:
ALTER TABLE `mysql.columns_priv` CHANGE COLUMN `User` `User` VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE `mysql.db` CHANGE COLUMN `User` `User` VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE `mysql.procs_priv` CHANGE COLUMN `User` `User` VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE `mysql.proxies_priv` CHANGE COLUMN `User` `User` VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE `mysql.tables_priv` CHANGE COLUMN `User` `User` VARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE `mysql.user` CHANGE COLUMN `user` `user` VARCHAR(100);

And solution will be work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the MySQL username length without recompiling the MySQL source.   See this note in the [5.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-names.html).  This is [also the case with MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-names.html).

> **Warning**
>
> The limit on MySQL user name length is hard-coded in the MySQL servers
>   and clients, and trying to circumvent it by modifying the definitions
>   of the tables in the mysql database does not work.

Comment: Looks like hard to find the hard-coded part in the code, i try a external solution, thanks!